# Java passing -D arguments using a file

Tags: java, command-line

I am running the command

```
java -jar -Darg1="1" -Darg2="2" -Darg3="3" -Darg4="4" -Darg5="5" -Darg6="6" app.jar
```

I want to pass a file which has all the properties instead of passing them using -D.

Is there any option in Java which can load these arguments from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java command does not support passing a property file for VM arguments.
Instead you can load a property file through your java code and then call :
"System.SetProperties(loadedProps)" in the early initialization of your code.